# load large svg in razor asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, svg

I have this file cshtml , and i have a large file svg stored under wwwroot/images

```
@{
    var svg = System.IO.Path.Combine(Model.Svg, "test.svg");
}

@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(svg));
```

and this is the HomeController

```
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment){
       _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;}

        public IActionResult TestSvg(LocalsViewModel model)
        {
            model.Svg = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            return View(model);
        }
```

the problem (This page isn’t working) with File.ReadAllText, even when i tried to @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText("test here")) always the same problem, contrariwise model.Svg already recovered with the correct path.

Comment: It will be easier to debug if you do all the logic to read the SVG content in the controller, then pass this as a string property in a model to the view. Set a breakpoint in the controller to see what is happening at each step.

Comment: thanks for ur answer , i did a debug and breakpoints , as i mentioned the problem in the views (@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(svg));
) ,This page isn’t working

Comment: I'm suggesting to move the `ReadAllText` call into the controller, where you can debug it.

Comment: @Noah Stahl , problem solved , thanks.